# "Not defined" using multiple callback functions (Node + EJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

In my app.js, I have the following:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    myLocation.find(function(err, locations) {
        if (err) {
            response.send(501, 'There was an error');
        }
        else {
            response.render('index', {
                locations:locations
            });
        }
        next();
    });
        app.get('/', function(request, response) {
        mySupplier.find(function(err, suppliers) {
            if (err) {
                response.send(501, 'There was an error');
            }
            else {
                response.render('index', {
                    suppliers:suppliers

                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am then trying to display all the information for both locations and suppliers in my index.ejs. I can get both to work individual, but not at the same time. I assume I am doing something wrong with the multiple callback functions to '/'.

This is my index.ejs

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="span12" style="border: 2px solid black">
                <% locations.forEach(function(location) { %>
                    <div>
                        <p><%= location.siteName %>,
                        <%= location.siteAddress %>,
                        <%= location.sitePhone %>,
                        <%= location.managerName %>,
                        <%= location.managerContact %>,
                        <%= location.managerEmail %></p>
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
            <div class="span12" style="border: 2px solid black">
                <% suppliers.forEach(function(supplier) { %>
                    <div>
                        <p><%= supplier.supName %>,
                        <%= supplier.supAddress %>,
                        <%= supplier.supPhone %>,
                        <%= supplier.supAltPhone %>,
                        <%= supplier.supEmail %>,
                        <%= supplier.supContact %></p>
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have been trying to solve this for hours now and just can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated, here is the error I am receiving if it's needed

```
ReferenceError: e:\Coding\wineCellar\views\index.ejs:34
    32|             </div>
    33|             <div class="span12" style="border: 2px solid black">
 >> 34|                 <% suppliers.forEach(function(supplier) { %>
    35|                     <div>
    36|                         <p><%= supplier.supName %>,
    37|                         <%= supplier.supAddress %>,

suppliers is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (e:\Coding\wineCellar\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:299:12), <anonymous>:2:3361)
    at e:\Coding\wineCellar\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:325:14
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (e:\Coding\wineCellar\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:195:31)
    at View.render (e:\Coding\wineCellar\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:75:8)
    at Function.app.render (e:\Coding\wineCellar\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:504:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (e:\Coding\wineCellar\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:753:7)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (e:\Coding\wineCellar\app.js:64:13)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (e:\Coding\wineCellar\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (e:\Coding\wineCellar\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:84:38)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're not using 'multiple callback functions' for your root route here. Here's how your code gets executed:

```
// 1. Define a route matching all get requests at '/'
app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    // 2. myLocation.find is invoked (async)
    myLocation.find(function(err, locations) {
        if (err) {
            response.send(501, 'There was an error');
        } else {
            // 5. Your response is rendered ???
            response.render('index', {
                locations: locations
            });
        }
        // 6. Attempt to invoke the next route match
        next();
    });
    // 3. A new route matcher is defined for '/'
    app.get('/', function(request, response) {
        mySupplier.find(function(err, suppliers) {
            if (err) {
                response.send(501, 'There was an error');
            } else {
                response.render('index', {
                    suppliers: suppliers

                });
            }
        });
    });
    // 4. app.get defined in #1 exits
});
```

I would suggest trying the following:

```
app.get('/',
    function(request, response) {
        // immediately execute location search
        myLocation.find(function(err, locations) {
            // fail if error in location search
            if (err) {
                return response.send(501, 'There was an error');
            }

            // otherwise, do a supplier search
            mySupplier.find(function(err, suppliers) {
                if (err) {
                    response.send(501, 'There was an error');
                } else {
                    // render the response with suppliers and location
                    response.render('index', {
                        suppliers: suppliers,
                        locations: locations
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    }
);
```

However you're querying for locations and suppliers, you'll probably want to write a query that retrieves a location and suppliers in one trip. Then you could get rid of the second asynchronous call.

Comment: Thank you, Jim for helping out the newbie. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: No problem. Strongloop (the company now maintaining Express.js) has a really good article on managing callbacks: http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/. This doesn't really apply to your current situation because you only have 2 continuations. But, as your logic gets hairier you may want to look at other ways of making your code easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    myLocation.find(function(err, locations) {
        if (err) {
            response.send(501, 'There was an error');
        }
        else {
            response.locals.locations = locations;
        }
        next();
    });
```

You can try this methods.